# While executing the stored procedure It is not giving expected output

Tags: postgresql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "internal"."get_last_weekday_of_month"(AsofDate TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9))
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
DECLARE
LastWeekDay TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9);
BEGIN
truncate table "internal"."monthend_process";
LastWeekDay := DATEADD(DAY,CASE DAYOFWEEK(AsofDate)
                               WHEN 6 THEN -1
                               WHEN 7 THEN -2
                               ELSE 0
                           END, AsofDate);

INSERT INTO "internal"."monthend_process" ("MonthEndDates","created_on", "RollOverStartDate",         "PrevPrevMonthEnd")
SELECT :LastWeekDay as "MonthEndDates", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), NULL,NULL
UNION
SELECT LAST_DAY(:AsofDate) as "MonthEndDates", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), NULL,NULL ;

UPDATE "internal"."monthend_process"
SET "RollOverStartDate" = DATEADD(DAY, -4, :AsofDate),
"PrevPrevMonthEnd" = LAST_DAY(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, :AsofDate));

  RETURN 'Stored procedure executed';
     END;
  $$;
```

This stored procedure is working fine, but when I am passing any Sunday date, then it is not returning Friday's date, and for Saturday, it is working fine it is returning Friday date.

Comment: I believe the following might help you, as Sunday's might be DAYOFWEEK() = 0 depending on the following:
[https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/year
The session parameter WEEK_START = 0 is set to indicate that the week starts on Monday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe if you changed the following:

```
LastWeekDay := DATEADD(DAY,CASE DAYOFWEEK(AsofDate)
                               WHEN 6 THEN -1
                               WHEN 7 THEN -2
                               ELSE 0
                           END, AsofDate);
```

To the below it should work as you expected:

```
LastWeekDay := DATEADD(DAY,CASE DAYOFWEEK(AsofDate)
                               WHEN 6 THEN -1
                               WHEN 0 THEN -2
                               ELSE 0
                           END, AsofDate);
```

Comment: Yes it worked 
Thanks!!

Comment: @MohitSharma please could you mark my reply as an Answer to your question, thanks! :)